# Categorical fields being converted to continuous after exporting csv using fwrite

Tags: r, csv, fwrite

I am facing some troubles with exporting a dataframe in R to csv as it seems to be converting my factors into numerics. Using summary() before exporting, I get the following:

```
 JobLevel JobSatisfaction
 1:1880   1:1448         
 2:3134   2:1343         
 3:1307   3:1996         
 4: 545   4:2327         
          5: 248
```

Then, I exported the file to CSV using the following command:

```
fwrite(HR, file = "Cleaned Data.csv")
```

However, when I imported the csv later, the categorical columns have seemingly been converted to continuous as such:

```
HR2 <- fread("Cleaned Data.csv", na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

```
    JobLevel     JobSatisfaction
 Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000
 1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:2.000
 Median :2.000   Median :3.000 
 Mean   :2.177   Mean   :2.731                  
 3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:4.000                  
 Max.   :5.000   Max.   :4.000
```

I believe gender is fine as it is a string but is there a way for me to export my factors with numeric levels such that when the csv is imported later, it would still remain as a factor.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV is a generic file format that is just Comma Separated Values. It doesn't contain any information about the classes of columns - that's up to the function that reads the CSV to decide.

To preserve class information when writing to a file the easiest way is to use an R-specific file format, like RDS (see `?readRDS` and `?saveRDS`). This works great if you only need R to read the file.

If you need other programs to be able to read/write the data too, then you'll need to keep track of the class information and, e.g., use the `colClasses` argument of `fread` to specify the column classes when you read in the CSV.